# Python Selenium Webdriver click though highlighted containers on website

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to scrape data from trading 212 and need to be able to iterate through each of the different investments which are displayed on the lhs of the webpage like so.

[image: Trading212 investments]

I want to click on each stock and loop through to the bottom of the list so I can scrape data from the page behind each of these icons. Aside from clicking each one by the full XPATH, is there an easier way to do it without having to know each XPATH?

[image: inspected html]

Comment: You can iterate through the list

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should **NEVER** use full XPath locators. As well as absolute CSS Selectors. You should use short, clean and stable **relative** XPath and CSS Selector locators.
Specifically to your question:
You can find a unique locator matching all the stock elements in that list and iterate thro that list without knowing the specific locator of each specific element.
As following:

```py
items = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[data-rbd-draggable-context-id='3']")))
for index, item in enumerate(items):
    items[index].click()
    #scrape the data of opened item
```

Here I used the list of "My watchlist" of that site. I couldn't find the view you presented on your question, but the approach is the same.
Here is the screenshot of that view:

[image]

Comment: Ok I follow that, thanks for the advice. In the table I am trying to iterate through, I have the class name as a unique locator element as follows - <div class="investment-item" data-qa-item="AIRp_EQ">. How would your code need to be altered to work on class name?

Comment: just change `[data-rbd-draggable-context-id='3']` to `.investment-item[data-qa-item='AIRp_EQ']`